# Dentist for a baby?

Tags: teeth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what age should I enroll my child in dental and vision plans?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/at-what-age-should-i-enroll-my-child-in-dental-and-vision-plans)

I'm sure this in a question only relevant to the US since we have to think about stuff like this, but what would be a reasonable age to sign up for dental insurance for my boy? Is this something that you would want before the teeth even erupt? Or are there only ever issues after you've moved to solids?

I guess a more general question would be: When do children start having issues with their teeth where they would need a dentist?